# Trouble defining a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

Alright, so a content page uses this:

```
$tab = "Friends";
$title = "User Profile"; 
include '(the header file, with nav)';
```

And the header page has the code:

```
if ($tab == "Friends") { 
echo '<li id="current">'; 
} else { 
echo '<li>'; 
}
```

The problem is, that the `if $tab == Friends` condition is never activated, and no other variables are carried from the the content page, to the header page.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Update:
Alright, the problem seemed to disappear when I used `../scripts/filename.php`, and only occurred when I used a full URL?

Any ideas why?

Comment: Pretty sure somewhere in your include you are redefining `$tab`.

Comment: What happens when you do var_dump($tab); in the header file?

Comment: $tab is empty, I tried. And I wasn't redefining it, when I changed the include url, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as posted should work. How are you actually including that file? Does that happen inside a function? Then you need to use the `global` statement for it to work. Example:

File 1:

```
function my_include($file) {
    global $tab; // <-- add this
    include '/some/path/' . $file;
}

$tab = 'Friends';
my_inlcude('file_2.php');
```

File 2:

```
if ($tab == 'Friends') { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, this would have fixed it, I decided to use relative URLs for the site instead, so it is portable. Thanks. I'll mark this as best when the time allows it.

Comment: @Jake however, using absolute path is always preferred. but, of course, absolute *filesystem path*, not virtual URL

Comment: am I overlooked something? why is there a function?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: A function would explain why the OP's code does not work. Because, as posted, the OP's code should work just fine. Included files inherit the scope of the line that the include is on. So, my guess is that the real code that the OP uses has a function call in there instead of just a plain include in the same scope as the variable assignment.

Comment: "So, my guess". I see. Great programming technique.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, agreed!  Guessing followed by testing is indeed a foundational programming (and scientific) technique.

Comment: @Kirk to let you know, that's false method. And it led poor fellow asked this question astray. He's believing that global was the cause

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: My question/assumption that the include happens inside a function is stated in the first line of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you `include` a full URL, you're not including the PHP script -- you're including the HTML it generates.  It's just like you went to `http://wherever.your.url.goes`, but it's done by the server instead of the browser.  The script runs in a whole separate process, caused by a separate request from the server to itself, and none of the `$variable`s are shared between the two.

Short version:  When you include `http://wherever.your.url.goes`, `$tab` will always be blank.  If you include the actual file name, the variable will be shared.

Answer (score 1):

1. Now you see why it's awful practice to post some stubs and skeches instead of the **real code**
2. Try to think, Your question is not a rocket science. Include is like copy-pasting code in place of include operator. Go load your inclided URL in browser, copy resulting code and paste it into your first file and see.

Comment: Surprisingly, I'm aware of how include works, the problem was me not realising $tab had to be set to global. Thanks for the unnecessarily brash answer though.